# How to avoid newline between enumeration and theorem?

Tags: enumerate, theorems

When I insert an theorem/definition environment at the start of an item of enumerate, it creates a newline automatically before **Theorem**. Is it somehow possible to remove this enforced newline so that the enumeration item (e.g. (a) ) is on the same line as the theorem beginning?

The following is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item % avoid newline here
    \begin{theorem} Some statement. \end{theorem}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the minimal example]

Comment: It's not really clear why you would have theorems in the middle of an enumerated list.

Comment: I use this construct for exercise sheets and solutions, i.e. enumerating points for each exercise (1. a), 1. b), etc.). In some of those points, there is a theorem/statement that needs to be proven. There may be a better way to do this to avoid having theorems in enumerations,  but I do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to 
define another environment for theorems which should not start with a line break. You can tweak the appearance if you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% For theorems which do not start with a line break
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nonewlinetheorem}
{\refstepcounter{theorem}\textbf{Theorem~\thetheorem.\space}\itshape}{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item \begin{theorem} Some statement. \end{theorem}
\item
  \begin{nonewlinetheorem}
    Another theorem statement.
  \end{nonewlinetheorem}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Better would be `\thetheorem` instead of `\arabic{theorem}` to get the current printing style of theorem numbers, e.g. if they are numbered within sections.

Comment: And you might wish to make the environment end with `\par`, to avoid the risk of having it gobble up following text into the same paragraph.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of a hack, but negative `\vspace` is a fairly common solution in LaTeX and will allow you to use this solution on any Theorem/Proposition/Lemma etc. environment you like without defining a new one for the purpose.
As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item \leavevmode \vspace{-2em}
    \begin{lemma} $e^{i\theta}\equiv\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta).$ \end{lemma}
\item \leavevmode \vspace{-2em}
    \begin{theorem} $e^{i\pi}=-1$. \end{theorem}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

gives the following:

[image: LaTex output]

Here `\leavevmode` is necessary to enter horizontal mode, otherwise `\vspace` produces a `\vskip` which ends the current paragraph, which does not then produce the desired affect.

Comment: I know this post is old, but I thought this solution might help any newcomers to the post.

Comment: Why `2em` and not something related to `\baselineskip`?